# How to match on different dict key values

Tags: python

I have the following code, im trying to obtain the outer dict key based on a test of the num key value, for example if chan_num is 248 i want to obtain the 'lifestyle & Culture' key, but at the moment i am always matching on the first item.

How can i achieve this?

```
chan_tags = {
    'Entertainment': {'num': 101, 'on': 1},
    'Lifestyle and Culture': { 'num': 240,  'on': 1 },
    'Movies': { 'num': 301,  'on': 1 }
    }

def chanToTag(chan_num, chan_tags):
    tag = ""
    for n in sorted(chan_tags, key=lambda k: chan_tags[k]['num']):
        if  chan_num >= chan_tags[n]['num']:
                tag = n            
                break
    return tag

tag_name = chanToTag(248, chan_tags)

print(tag_name)
```

Comment: commenting out the break or deleting it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate bigger num entry first. Passing `reverse=True` keyword argument make `sorted` sort in reverse order:

```
def chanToTag(chan_num, chan_tags):
    for n in sorted(chan_tags, key=lambda k: chan_tags[k]['num'], reverse=True):
        if chan_num >= chan_tags[n]['num']:
            return n
    return ''
```